# ssh connection reuse breaks -f (background launch), why?

Tags: ssh, background-process

When not using connection sharing the following will return immediately after launching a remote sleep process:

`$ ssh -f host "nohup sleep 10"`

However if I specify that I want to use connection sharing in ~/.ssh/config like this:

```
host *
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
```

The same command will block for 10 seconds until the sleep exits. Why is this?

Comment: From what I can tel this is a bug in ssh. I was able to work around this by using: ```ssh host "nohup sleep 10 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &"```

Comment: You could add `-t` to command^ `$ ssh -t -f host "nohup sleep 10"`